# bitmap store on Samsung device is pixelated and cannot be found it in folder. fixed only after device restart

Tags: android, file, bitmap

i trying to create a full screenshot of a listview wrapped inside HorizontalScrollView.
when i save image file and open it from the my app the image is pixelated and can't find the image in my device. it happens only in Samsung devices on all other devices works fine.
after i restart the Samsung device everything is OK.
any ideas?
here my code

this is how i create my bitmap

```
        if (views.size() > 0) {
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(table_layout.getWidth(),
                    ((currentPlayers.size() + 1) * views.get(0).getHeight()) + table_layout.getHeight(),
                    Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
        } else {
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(table_layout.getWidth(),
                    table_layout.getHeight(),
                    Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
        }
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        Drawable background = report_view.getBackground();
        if (background != null) {
            background.draw(canvas);
        } else {
            //does not have background drawable, then draw white background on the canvas
            canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        }

        canvas.translate(0, table_layout.getHeight());
        table_layout.draw(canvas);
        if (views.size() > 0) {
            for (View v : views) {
                canvas.translate(0, v.getHeight());
                v.draw(canvas);
            }
        }
        imageFile = new File(mPath);
```

than i draw using canvas

and than saving to device in AsyncTask

```
    FileOutputStream  outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);

        int quality = 100;
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, outputStream);
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();

        reportActivity.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.parse(tempPath.replace("/storage/emulated/0", "file://"))));
        //tempPath = mPath;
        msg = "File saved: \n" + tempPath.replace("/storage/emulated/0", "");
        oneBtn = false;
```

Comment: Don't use Samsung devices, they totally destroy Android's rep. and don't fix the problems they create.

Answer (score 1):

try to this code.

```
private void RefreshGallary() {
Intent RefreshGallaryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
File f = new File("Your Current Photo Path");
Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
RefreshGallaryIntent .setData(contentUri);
this.sendBroadcast(RefreshGallaryIntent );
```

}